# Visible Property in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

During working with a constantly growing ERM, I came to the idea that a view-toggle feature would be very neat, so I can e.g. hide all tables depending to the plugin xyz.

I am working with MySQL Workbench and found this answer in the  documentations:

> In some circumstances, you may want to make a layer invisible. Select the layer and, in the Properties
>   palette, set the visible property to False.

My problem is: There is no Visible property, not in the properties of single tables, neither in the properties of Layers.

I am using the newest version of the tool.

Does somebody knows what's going wrong (perhaps there's a special setting/configuration to use that property), or if somebody knows if they have removed this function?

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? Same problem here

Comment: @JavierEnríquez No, sadly there still seems to be no option to hide  certain layers (version 6.3). It's still described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-modifying-layer.html) as a feature, although it says [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-properties-palette.html) that the visibility property is only available for relationships (Then again, there it doesn't show up in the properties palette, but in the edit window).